# How to Get a Highest Number Score after Compare it in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Let say, I have this Data: (Exam ID, Exam Name, & Exam Score)

```
Exam ID | Exam Name | Score
----------------------------
Exam_1  | Exam 1 | 95

Exam_2  | Exam 2 | 67

Exam_3  | Exam 3 | 77

Exam_4  | Exam 4 | 97
```

I want to compare the score and get only the highest score to show it using My SQL, Based on table above, I want to get only the highest score, it means `Exam_4 | Exam 4| 97`

I got an Idea to use `sort descending` to do it. But I can't quite implement the logic correctly since I must Check Every ID and after that Compare the score, How Can I Solve this Problem Using MySQL?

Can someone Help me to solve this? I'm Quite Confused about this

**EDIT 1**

Sorry I forgot to mention this,

Every Exam can be take by Student at least 2 times, So the exact tables Will looks like this:

```
Student Id | Exam ID | Exam Name | Score
-------------------------------------
Student A | Exam_1 | Exam 1 | 95

Student A | Exam_2 | Exam 2 | 67

Student A | Exam_3 | Exam 3 | 77

Student A | Exam_4 | Exam 4 | 97 (Student A Highest Score)

Student B | Exam_1 | Exam 1 | 66

Student B | Exam_3 | Exam 3 | 87 (Student B Highest Score)

Student B | Exam_4 | Exam 4 | 57

Student C | Exam_1 | Exam 1 | 56 (Student C Highest Score)

Student C | Exam_2 | Exam 2 | 37

Student C | Exam_3 | Exam 3 | 47

Student D | Exam_1 | Exam 1 | 88 (Student D Highest Score)

Student D | Exam_4 | Exam 4 | 79
```

So what I want to Achieve is, I want to get The Highest score for Every Student such as Like This:

```
Student Id | Exam ID | Exam Name | Score
-------------------------------------
Student A | Exam_4 | Exam 4 | 97 (Student A Highest Score)

Student B | Exam_3 | Exam 3 | 87 (Student B Highest Score)

Student C | Exam_1 | Exam 1 | 56 (Student C Highest Score)

Student D | Exam_1 | Exam 1 | 88 (Student D Highest Score)
```

Comment: `order by Score desc limit 1`

Comment: 'since I must Check Every ID and after that Compare the score' - can you expand on this?

Comment: Ah yes, I'm just remember about it, I mean Let say Every User Can Take 2 until 4 Exam so Every User will have `at least 2 exam` such as `User A have Score for Exam 1, Exam 2, & Exam 4`, `User B Have Score for Exam 2 & Exam 3`, etc. let me update the question a bit

Comment: You need highest score - per user? per exam? per whole data array?

Comment: I already Update My Question above, As for @Akina What I want to achieve is to get Highest Score - for every Student in exam regardless of what exam they take

Comment: Per student... now specify your MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina this is MySQL version`5.7.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 5+ MySQL version:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM sourcetable t1
JOIN ( SELECT t2.`Student Id`, MAX(t2.Score) Score
       FROM sourcetable t2 
       GROUP BY t2.`Student Id` ) t3 USING (`Student Id`, Score);
```

For MySQL 8+:

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY `Student Id` ORDER BY Score DESC) rnk
              FROM sourcetable )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Anycase if some student have equal highest mark for 2 or more exams all of them will be returned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let me try it first

Comment: Thankyou Akina for your answer, when I tweak my code several time finally it works using your answer, at first I got stuck how to implement you code, and finally it works! ^.^